# PHP date_default_timezone_set()

Tags: php, timezone

In php, is there a way to set default timezone in .htaccess or wherever, as long as i don have to set it at every php page.

provided i don have access to server, only PHP files. Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

i am using apache (LAMP), and don't have access to php.ini

Comment: It's generally set in `php.ini`.

Comment: The short answer is "yes" but the more thoughtful answer might be to ask yourself if you will ever have clients in different timezones and if you want to be responsive to their local timezones.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Considering you use apache from the fact you mention .htaccess:

Yes, as long as it runs mod_php it is possible in .htaccess like so:

```
php_value date.timezone "Europe/Berlin"
```

Or you could set date.timezone in php.ini like Karl Laurentius Roos suggested. This would only be possible if you have access to your php config through. Remember to restart PHP (CGI mode) or your webserver (mod_php) after altering php.ini.

Comment: `php_value date.timezone "Europe/Warsaw"` for Polish websites!

Comment: Yes, there are a few more. This is just an example timezone. You may see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones for more examples.

Answer (score 3):

Set `date.timezone` in your php.ini. Supported timezone values: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Answer (score 2):

I was getting 500 (Internal server Error) using the code

`php_value date.timezone "Europe/Berlin"`.

Then I tried, `SetEnv TZ Australia/Melbourne` and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

If you get a 500 error you might try checking for the PHP5 module, works for me.

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value date.timezone "Europe/Lisbon"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding below code in **.htaccess** file from CPanel Server. 
I used to get 500 (Internal server Error)

```
#Adjust default time zone 

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value date.timezone "Asia/Kolkata"
</IfModule>

SetEnv TZ Asia/Kolkata
```

Then I navigated to the **cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor) >> Edit PHP INI settings** 
**OR** 
 Go to the Path **/homecws/Your_folder_name/public_html/php.ini** then
include 
`date.timezone=Asia/Kolkata` in **php.ini** file

Here is the complete php.ini file

```
; magic_quotes_gpc = Off;
; register_globals = Off;
; default_charset   = UTF-8;
; memory_limit = 64M;
; max_execution_time = 36000;
; upload_max_filesize = 999M;
; safe_mode = Off;
; mysql.connect_timeout = 20;
; session.auto_start = Off;
; session.use_only_cookies = On;
; session.use_cookies = On;
; session.use_trans_sid = Off;
; session.cookie_httponly = On;
; session.gc_maxlifetime = 3600;
; allow_url_fopen = on;
; ;display_errors = 1;
; ;error_reporting = E_ALL;



allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = On
asp_tags = Off
display_errors = On
enable_dl = Off
file_uploads = On
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 600
max_input_vars = 10000
memory_limit = 512M
session.gc_maxlifetime = 14400
session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56"
upload_max_filesize = 2000M
post_max_size = 8M
zlib.output_compression = On
date.timezone = Asia/Kolkata
```

This solved and worked for mine.

Answer (score 0):

If the server is properly configured and you want to set your process time-zone to this server value (if not set), then in the doc-root `.htaccess` you can set a PHP file to run before any other PHP file -and in this file you can define a couple of configurations, functions and classes to use as "tools"  which will be available in all the other PHP files - like this:

**.htaccess**

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "path/of/file.php"
```

**path/of/file.php**

```
date_default_timezone_set(ini_get('date.timezone'));
```