# Set timezone for specific folder?

Tags: php

I want to set a specific folder to another timezone in the php.ini file so I don't have to set it manually in each file within the folder.

```
[Date]
date.timezone = Europe/Berlin

Folder[Date] /* something like this? */
date.timezone = America/New_York
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by Folder? Do you mean a domain?

Comment: No, I mean a folder in a domain. I'm working on localhost and have a folder called "stocks," which I want in New York time.

Comment: then no, that makes no sense. how about explaining how the time is used for the particular files

Comment: In that case, can you explain  what your folder structure represents? PHP doesn't have a concept of folders, it's a programming language; not a filesystem

Comment: date.timezone can be set on a per directory basis in htaccess.

Comment: @MarkBaker sorry Mark, I'm not sure I follow. I have localhost/stocks and localhost/other_folders.

Comment: @OrangePill could you elaborate on this? Perhaps provide an answer :)

Comment: add `php_value date.timezone "America/New_York"` to .htaccess in that directory "should" work.

Comment: @JohnSmith elaborated and answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use .htaccess to set the default timezone on a per directory basis.

Just add

```
php_value date.timezone "America/New_York"
```

to an .htaccess file in that directory and make sure your server supports per directory configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Use [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) in the scripts in that folder.

You can also set it in htaccess:

```
php_value date.timezone "America/New_York"
```

For this to work, you need to use [mod_php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712825/what-is-mod-php) in Apache. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916481/php-date-default-timezone-set).

Comment: for every file? so... include a file that sets this in every file? that feels very redundant.

Comment: Not every file, but every entry point. If every request runs through a single index.php, you can put it in there. If every script includes a general purpose library for connecting to a database or so, you can put it in there. If your scripts are actually completely separate scripts with nothing in common, then I think you're one of the very few. Most sites run through a common entry point script.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably also use in the .htaccess file:

```
SetEnv TZ America/New_York
```

Which should work on every system, php_value may not work on certain servers. But I would really recommend using the normal php function:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

in a specific file that has the configuration specific to your script, and then just include the file in your other files.

Answer (score 0):

These answers are all correct when using a webserver, however this doesn't work running a PHP CLI script, for ie. a cronjob. PHP would use the `date.timezone` setting defined in `php.ini`.

Best practice would be, to just call `date_default_timezone_set` on top of your application wrapper/bootstrap file.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```